# редирект после создания комментария на страницу поста Django

Tags: django

Есть модель комментариев

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор комментария')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Комментарий')
    com_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания комментария')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Есть вьюха которая их добавляет

```
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['object_id', 'comment']
    #success_url = ?

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Не получается сделать редирект на страницу с постом после добавления комментариев. Понимаю что нужно использовать   success_url = reverse_lazy('post_detail',  ?? ), но не получается передать аргументы.

Get_absolute_url модели поста выглядит:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'category': self.category.slug, 'slug': self.slug})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В модели `Comment` должен быть определён метод `get_absolute_url`, возвращающий URL комментируемого поста, тогда `CreateView` вызовет его для получения `success_url`. Это [описано в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms).

Comment: Да я это понимаю. Только не понимаю как из этой модели вытащить слаги категории и поста.

Comment: `content_object.get_absolute_url()` и всё.